# Oracle BETWEEN operator with text values

Tags: sql, oracle

#### Query 1:

```
SELECT cust_last_name, cust_credit_limit
FROM customers
WHERE (UPPER(cust_last_name) LIKE 'A%' OR
       UPPER(cust_last_name) LIKE 'B%' OR
       UPPER(cust_last_name) LIKE 'C%' AND cust_credit_limit < 10000;
```

#### Query 2:

```
SELECT cust_last_name,cust_credit_limit
FROM customers
WHERE UPPER(cust_last_name) BETWEEN 'A' AND 'C' AND
cust_credit_limit < 10000;
```

I am trying to generate a report of last names and credit limits of all the customers whose last names start with A, B or C and credit limit is below 10000. 
Which is the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly use between A and C because the values that start with C like CDE will not be included. Since you need all the row starting with A to starting
with C, you could use a custom range:

```
select cust_last_name, cust_credit_limit
from customers
where UPPER(cust_last_name) >= 'A'
  and UPPER(cust_last_name) < 'D'
  and cust_credit_limit < 10000
```

It finds all strings that are between A (inclusive) and D (exclusive).

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/HUI30454)

or use maybe substr:

```
select cust_last_name, cust_credit_limit
from customers
where UPPER(substr(cust_last_name,1,1)) between 'A' and 'C'
    and cust_credit_limit < 10000
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/XGQWXB33826)

Answer (score 0):

Oracle is likely to use an index for the following query:

```
select cust_last_name, cust_credit_limit
from customers
where ((cust_last_name >= 'A' and cust_last_name < 'D') or
       (cust_last_name >= 'a' and cust_last_name < 'd')
      ) and
      cust_credit_limit < 10000;
```

For performance, I would suggest that you go with the `upper()` version and create an index on `customers(upper(cust_last_name), cust_credit_limit)`.

Comment: How do you know that these indexes will be beneficial, without knowing the cardinalities?

Comment: @BobC . . . I realized that after answering.  With the given ranges, these might not be sufficiently selective.